# Google apps script store script property value as an integer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to store script property value as an integer.

```
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('setnumber'))
  {
     var setnumber = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('setnumber')) + Number(1); 
  }
  else
  {
     var setnumber = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('setnumber', 1)); // this value gets stored as 1.0 or returns undefined 
  }  

    var numofrow = 500;
    var maxvalue = numofrow * setnumber; //returns undefined
```

Comment: What does setProperty return?

Comment: @Jonasw returns either 1.0 or undefined (Nan).

Comment: probably not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setProperty` doesn't returns the value, it rather sets a value to a property. Refer the below code.

```
 var setnumber = 1;
     if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('setnumber'))
      {
         setnumber = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('setnumber')) + 1; 
         PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('setnumber', setnumber);
      }
      else
      {
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('setnumber', setnumber); // you can't assign this to a variable
      }  
         var numofrow = 500;
        var maxvalue = numofrow * setnumber; //returns undefined
        Logger.log(maxvalue)
```

Comment: I run this script the first time I get maxvalue 500, the second time its 1000 and after that any number of times I run it the maxvalue is always 1000 the third time I expected the maxvalue 1500 and so on...

Comment: @PVB, did this help?